# Google XML Export with repeating lines

Tags: xml, excel

I have a Excel 2013 Table with a few rows and columns. I want to export that data to an XML to be able to combine it with more XML and remap the data.

However, I am struggling to get Excel to accept my XML definition as a multi-line definition.

This is my definition:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Dossiers-Root" /> 
- <xsd:complexType name="EinzelneDossiers">
- <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="Dossier" type="DossierType" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:complexType name="DossierType">
- <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="Signatur_1" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Signatur_2" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Titel" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Form_und_Inhalt" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Zeilenzahl" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Zeitraum_von" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Zeitraum_bis" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Vol" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Tag" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Anmerkungen_pers" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Anmerkungen_div" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Bewertung_und_Kassation" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Ordnung_und_Klassifikation" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Zugangsbestimmungen" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Beschaffenheit" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Bearbeitungsnotizen" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
```

When importing the scheme excel does not even properly read the nodes, it just shows the topmost header. Unfortunately I cannot post pics yet.

Can some XML guru help me out? I got a smiliar sheet to work with only one row of data..

Thanks,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Now that I managed to get the thing working, I thought I'd share the correct definition with you. It all came down to the number and order of the ** sequences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Mit XMLSpy v2014 rel. 2 (http://www.altova.com) von Claudia Schreiber (AfA Archiv GmbH) bearbeitet -->
<!-- Schema für Archivverzeichnis (Dossiers, Tab3) / 2014-04-29 pl -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Gesamtdossiers">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Dossier" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:all>
                            <xsd:element name="Signatur_1" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Signatur_2" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Titel" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Form_und_Inhalt" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Zeilenzahl" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Zeitraum_von" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Zeitraum_bis" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Vol" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Tag" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Anmerkungen_pers" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Anmerkungen_div" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Bewertung_und_Kassation" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Ordnung_und_Klassifikation" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Zugangsbestimmungen" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Beschaffenheit" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Bearbeitungsnotizen" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:all>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Cheers, Pascal